# How to hightlight source code using codemirror on a html page

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I am currently highlighting the source on my website using google's prettyprint like below on my website.

```
<pre class="prettyprint css">
  div {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 25px solid red;
    margin: 25px;
}
</pre>
```

I will already have some code on file but I only want to hightlight that code.
How can I highlight the same using codemirror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it shown in codemirror.net

create an `<textarea>` element, which will replace yuor current `<pre>` tag. set textarea to `readonly` if you prefer no edit.

```
<textarea id="myTextarea" readonly>
... your code for highlighting goes here ...
</textarea>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script>
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("myTextarea"), {
    lineNumbers: true
  });
</script>
```

multiple instances selected by a common class name:

```
var areas = document.getElementsByClassName("myTextareaClass");
for(var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {   
  CodeMirror.fromTextArea(areas.item(i), {lineNumbers: true});
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working okay however there is another issue am facing while using your solution.
If have to highlight  code in three different places <textarea id="myTextarea" > this line is only highlighting the first code but it is not highlighting the other two sample codes.

Comment: repeat it 3 times for each area, or make a cycle using the same class for areas using `document.getElementsByClassName`.  I will edit my answer to show you how.

Comment: Here is the thing I did as you said by giving a class name to each textarea. However it is still not highlighting the second and third textareas.
http://pastebin.com/ASBjxTf5

Comment: same class name to all areas called 'myTextareaClass'?

Comment: please provide your code and I'' tell you what you are missing ... you can do a fiddler example as many people do ... but i think it will be difficult for you

Comment: Here is code and link for codepen. In this code you can see that the second and third textareas are not been highlighted.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpjXdZ

Comment: `keyMap :"sublime"` has something improper an causes an exception. Javascript leaves the executed block after the point of the exception and the rest is not executed, so you have just the first box codemirrored. Use `try { CodeMirror.fromTextArea(...);  } catch (e) { console.log(e) }` to see the error in your browser console, if you want to use this option `keyMap :"sublime"`.